# c++ find repeated substring within string

Tags: c++, string, function, search

Im trying to find the number of times a substring repeats within a string input but for some reason when I call the function it gives me a weird number. I have already tested the function within main and it works fine but when I make a standalone function it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int checkHope(string word1)
    {
    int answer;
    int counter;
    for(int i = 0; word1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        answer = word1.find("h", i);
        if ((word1.find("o", (answer+1)) == i+1) && (word1.find("e", (answer+3)) == i+3)) counter++;
    }
    return counter;
    }

int main()
{
    string word1;

    cout << "Please enter a word to check how many times the word \"hope\" appears. You can also have any letter instead of p.: ";
    getline(cin, word1);
    cout << checkHope(word1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try initializing `counter` to 0.  When you don't it's random what it starts out as.

Comment: uhuuuu it works.... what a stupid question tho... thank you @RetiredNinja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//This will work, 
//Changes initialize counter to 0, add condition to check alphabet 'p' also in if condition


#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int checkHope(string word1)
{
  int answer;
  int counter=0;
  for(int i = 0; word1[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    answer = word1.find("h", i);
    if ((word1.find("o", (answer+1)) == i+1)
          &&  (word1.find("p", (answer+2)) == i+2)
          && (word1.find("e", (answer+3)) == i+3))
           counter++;
  }
  return counter;
}

int main()
{
  string word1;

  cout << "Please enter a word to check how many times the word \"hope\" appears. You can also have any letter instead of p.: ";
  getline(cin, word1);
  cout << checkHope(word1);

  return 0;
}
```